# How to identify the pattern "_000n." in a string using regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string and in certain places, the pattern "`_000n.`" (n is an integer) exists. How do I read the integer portion within "_" and "." using Regex. I do not want to use simple search in string because there could be other places with these characters but not with the correct number of integers. I would like to know the regex pattern for this.

Comment: There are many (interactive!) regular expression tutorials, and this question shows no prior effort.

Comment: add examples of your input and output

Comment: So, is this a valid pattern `_0001234.`? What about `_0012.`? Or is it simply `_0000.` through `_0009.`, i.e., `n` is a digit, not an integer. If it is, then consider something simple like `@"_(000\d)\."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really simple regex should do the trick :

```
_(\d*)\.
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZFN9q1/1/

Comment: Thank you very much. I want this number length to be restricted to be 4.

Comment: I modified it to _(\d\d\d\d).. Hope this is good

Comment: @pcg: then what is the significance of the leading `000`?. If all you want is a 4 digit number, then both `\d\d\d\d` and `\d{4}` would work.